# how to use visible=<%# ShowOrHide %> with tr?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, asp.net-3.5

In a aspx page  I have table as container and tds have different Repeaters in it.

I know table is not a databound control but was wondering there may be a way to use data from dt to control visibility of a tr or any other html control ?

I just tried Page.Databind() but it was not successful and there was an error "Table is not a data bound control"

Please guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use DISPLAY property to ensure that a blank space is not left by the row that is hidden instead of the VISIBLE property.

With out knowing or seeing your code block for a a sible gle its difficult to second guess  but if your using "Show" or Hide" as the swutches to decide wether to show or hide a row.........

maybe your code should read as follows.....

```
<tr <%=GetDisplayStatus('switch') %>>
```

where switch is either "show" or "hide" and your SERVERSIDE function to get the display status should be as follows..

```
Function GetDisplayStatus(SwitchState as String) as String
  If SwitchState = "show" then
    return " style=" & chr(34) & "display: block;" & chr(34)
  ElseIf SwitchState = "hide" Then
    return " style=" & chr(34) & "display: none;" & chr(34)
  Else
    ' no action otherwise
    return ""
  End If
End Function
```

Please let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

When working with ASP.Net, it's important to know which properties are processed by the server and which are html. When you use a `<%#` tag, the value in your expression is written directly to the web server's response stream. It's too late at this point to assign to a server property. Visible is a server property.